# Why there is an extra line in JQPlot draggable line

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqplot

Like the official tutorial [showed](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html),it only defined one line in it, that is s1 = [['23-May-08',1],['24-May-08',4],['25-May-08',2],['26-May-08', 6]];

[image]
But, why the chart has the second line? How to delete it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `$.jqplot.Trendline` is included on the page. if you remove that file then you will not see the line (trendline).

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cCns9/1/)